# UILocalNotification every Saturday at 12:00 am

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, uilocalnotification, repeat, nsdatecomponents

I try to repeat UILocalNotification every Saturday but I didn't succeed.
I try the following:

```
// Create notification for every saturday at 12:00 am
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSUIntegerMax fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setWeekday:7]; // Saturday
[components setHour:12]; // 12 am
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];

NSDate *fireDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];         
NSLog(@"%@", fireDate);

[[NotificationsManager sharedManager] configureLocalAlertMessage:message
                                                                    fireDate:fireDate
                                                          repeatIntervalUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit
                                                                        type:kNotificationTypeMoneyBox];
```

But "fireDate" returns: "2013-03-12 11:00:00 +0000" ie today.

Any help?
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Code to configure notification

```
- (void)configureLocalAlertMessage:(NSString *)message fireDate:(NSDate *)date repeatIntervalUnit:(NSCalendarUnit)repeat type:(NotificationType)type {

    // Local notification
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    notification.fireDate = date;
    notification.repeatInterval = repeat;
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.hasAction = YES;
    notification.alertBody = message;
    notification.userInfo = @{kNotificationTypeKey : @(type)};
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    // Schedule
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

}
```

Comment: where is the code where you setup the Local Notification.  This code is just for creating date.

Comment: "When there is inconsistent information, a calendar may ignore some of the components parameters or the method may return nil. "

Comment: Ok, but how can I do? I need programming UILocalNotification for every  saturday at 12:00 am during 12 weeks...

Comment: Supply consistent info.  NSCalendar has no  idea what date to put into the NSDate, so apparently it's defaulting to today.

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =[gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit |               NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:idate];

    int weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
    NSDate *nextdate ;
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    if(weekday <= 5)
    {
       /* it is my case to check the weekday, if it is less or greater than 5*/
    }
    else
    {
        [offsetComponents setDay:7];
        [offsetComponents setHour:12];
        [offsetComponents setMinute:0];
        [offsetComponents setSecond:0];
        nextdate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:idate options:0];
    }
    [offsetComponents release];
    [gregorian release];
```

you can use this **next date** as a fire date for your local notification. 
Here **idate** is NSDate *idate = [NSDate date];